# php/JS form question

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, list

I am new to php and JS and I have this code I have been stuck on that I cant get to work:

my something.php just has `$variable= $_POST['SUBMIT']`
`echo $variable`

```
<?php
$list=$_POST['added'];
?>

<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js'></script> 

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css"> 

  <style type='text/css'> 


#display{
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:white;
}

#display div {
    clear: both;
}
#display div span{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.edit {
    color: blue;
}

.delete {
    color: red;
}



   body {background-color:orange;}
p {color:orange;
   size=3;
}

  body {

  background-image: url("http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/rogers_blackberry_8900.jpg");

  background-position: 50% 50%;

  background-repeat: repeat;

}

  </style> 

  <script type='text/javascript'> 
  //<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#add').click(function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'Add';
    var input = $('#addInput');
    var display = $('#display');
    var form = $('#addForm');
    if ($.trim(input.val()).length > 0) { //is there input?
        var div = $('<div>').append($('<span>', {
            text: input.val()
        }), $('<span>', {
            text: 'delete',
            class: 'delete'
        }), $('<span>', {
            text: 'edit',
            class: 'edit'
        }))
        display.append(div);
        form.append($('<input>', {
            value: input.val(),
            type: 'hidden',
            name: 'added[]'
        }));
        input.val('');
        }
    })



    $('.edit').live('click', function(){
        $('#add').html('Edit');
        var input = $('#addInput');
        var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        input.val($(this).parent().children().get(0).innerHTML); //show value
        $(this).parent().remove(); //remove it from the list
        $('#addForm').children().eq(index).remove();
    });

    $('.delete').live('click', function(){
        var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        $('#addForm').children().eq(index).remove();
        $(this).parent().remove(); //remove it from the list
    });




  });


  //]]> 
  </script> 

  <title>Admin Phone Setup</title>
</head> 
<body> 

<STYLE>H2 {FONT-SIZE: 21pt; COLOR: #ff3399}; </STYLE>
<CENTER>
<H2>Twilio Admin Setup</H2>
</CENTER>


<p id="demo">Enter Phone Numbers</p>
  <input id="addInput"/> <button id="add">Add</button> 
<div id='display'></div> 
<form action="something.php" id="addForm"> 
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/> 
</form>   
</body> 
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is once a person adds a bunch of numbers into that list and clicks submit it should send those values to something.php so I can use those values...I am really stuck and dont know what I am doing wrong...I think it might be the variable or some issue with my display list.

Comment: At a glance my recommendation is to try placing the inputs within the <form> tag, as submitting a form sends only the inputs specified within the tag.

Comment: And since your php file looks for _POST, add method="post" when opening your form (i.e.) <form action="something.php" id="addForm" method="post">

Comment: Your PHP file seems to be looking for an input named SUBMIT, but no such input exists...

Comment: The values are getting through array, so use array values for getting your values after submitted. `$_POST['added'][]`. Before that do not forget to add method attribute to post in your form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your button is unnamed. To get the buttons value, you must assing a name attribute, e.g.

```
<input type="submit" name="mysubmitbutton" value="SUBMIT" />
```

2) In your something.php you are using the POST-array, but your form is submitted with GET-data, because there is no 'method' attribute on your form tag. Also it seems that you try to access the buttons value by using its value as index (that does not word ;) ). You have the choice (after nameing the button)
a) use $_GET['mysubmitbutton'] in your PHP-Script
b) change your form tag to

```
<form ... method="post" ... >
```

and use $_POST['mysubmitbutton'].

Comment: I have fixed it but now the problem is it shows "SUBMIT" when I click the submit button...so something.php shows submit...It is suppose to show the list of numbers I added to the list..

Comment: Iterate over you *added* array and echo the items. e.g. foreach($_POST['added'] as $item) {echo $item . '<br />'; }